# F# Why do I get this return type?

Tags: f#

Simple question.

I have a function which takes two strings and an int, and returns a new string with `n` lines and which alternates between the two input strings.

```
let rec f s1 s2 n = function
    | s1 when n > 0 -> s1 + "\n" + f s2 s1 (n-1)
    | s2 when n > 0 -> s2 + "\n" + f s1 s2 (n-1)
```

Calling it

```
f "ab" "cd" 4
```

Should return `ab\ncd\nab\ncd`

I currently get an error in my method `string -> string -> int -> (string -> 'a)` and I'm not sure why. Any hints?

UPDATE:

As it turns out, it's caused by using the anonymous `function`. Changing it to a `match` expression solves it:

```
let rec f s1 s2 n = 
    match s1 with
    | _ when n <= 0 -> ""
    | s1 when n > 0 -> s1 + "\n" + f s2 s1 (n-1)
    | s2 when n > 0 -> s2 + "\n" + f s1 s2 (n-1)
```

UPDATE 2: The above function might be a step in the right direction, but the below implementation is the correct one as pointed out by [TheQuickBrownFox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46753186/4101765).

```
let rec f s1 s2 n = 
    if n <= 0 then ""
    else s1 + "\n" + f s2 s1 (n-1)
```

Comment: I've updated my answer following your update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `function` keyword creates a new anonymous function (or lambda) with one argument and goes straight into a pattern match.

So your `f` function takes `s1`, `s2` and `n` and then returns another function as the value. It's the same as writing this:

```
let rec f s1 s2 n =
    fun x ->
        match x with
        | s1 when n > 0 -> s1 + "\n" + f s2 s1 (n-1)
        | s2 when n > 0 -> s2 + "\n" + f s1 s2 (n-1)
```

It's not clear to me what your function is trying to do so I can't suggest a fix for you. I would recommend staying away from the `function` keyword altogether for now. Try writing this function in this form and see if it helps:

```
let rec f s1 s2 n =
    match ... with
    ...
```

---

**UPDATE:**

In your updated implementation, you're not actually using pattern matching at all. The pattern part is effectively being discarded and the `when` clause is doing all of the work. Furthermore, it's impossible to ever reach the last branch because either `n <= 0` or `n > 0`. Your new function can be written more simply:

```
let rec f s1 s2 n = 
    if n <= 0 then ""
    else s1 + "\n" + f s2 s1 (n-1)
```

Comment: Do you get a notification every time someone posts an F# question? :p

Comment: Yep. If you hover on a tag you can subscribe to it by email :)

Comment: I was able to get to a right solution using your suggestion of omitting the function keyword.